# Best pattern to apply a navigation property to an abstract model such as an address?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to SQL and the Entity Framework.  I seek help regarding a design question surrounding these two concepts.

When modelling a one to many relationship, I understand that it is necessary to have a foreign key on the dependent end of the relationship.  This means that an abstract model, such as an address, must contain a navigation property to any other model that implements more than one address.

In lieu of this, I wonder if using inheritance to add a navigation property to the abstract model is the right approach, or if perhaps, there is a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do.  In all the reading I've done regarding the Entity Framework, I've not seen mention of this pattern. Therefore, I feel this must be an anti-pattern, and there must be a better way.  Please see below for an example of what I mean:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid RowId { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Address : BaseEntity
{
    public string Street1 { get; set; }
    public string Street2 { get; } set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string StateProvince { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class PersonAddress : Address
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class MerchantAddress : Address
{
    public Guid MerchantId { get; set; }
    public virtual Merchant Merchant { get; set; }
}

public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    // person properties

    public ICollection<PersonAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Merchant : BaseEntity
{
    // merchant properties

    public ICollection<MerchantAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

and finally with the fluent api:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Addresses)
                .WithRequired(a => a.Person)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.PersonId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Merchant>()
                .HasMany(m => m.Addresses)
                .WithRequired(a => a.Merchant)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.MerchantId);
}
```

Thank you very much for lending humble self your time and attention with this question.

Comment: Charlie, just a hint: try to look for something about TPT, TPH and TPC. There are 2 different "worlds" about this topic, and they're the Database você Class Model. When talking about "Class Model" you have some patterns (like the inhyeritance and use of common abstract classes), but when you have to put it on the Database (which doesn't have those concepts) then, there are some strategies that you should know about.

Comment: And about your code, it doesn't looks that strange at all for me (no anti-pattern imao).

Comment: Thank you, Marcelo.  I am most grateful for your assessment of humble code.  I have researched the different table generation options within the entity framework.  I have not yet mastered this, but so far, I find that sometimes it's best to combine TPH and TPC depending on the model type.  Addresses, for instance, may be best suited to share many Foreign Key columns, but Employees and Customers should not share a table as a Person model

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the right way to do it.

You could also do it the opposite way.

```
public class Address : BaseEntity // Not abstract
{
    public int HumanId { get; set; }
    public Human Human { get; set; }

    public string Street1 { get; set; }
    public string Street2 { get; } set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string StateProvince { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Then abstract a Human class (whatever the name).

```
public abstract class Human : BaseEntity
{
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class People : Human
{
}

public class Merchant : Human
{
}
```

It feels more natural this way to me.

Comment: I am grateful for your insight.  In the case of merchant, I meant "business," so an address may belong to something other than a human.  I would still need to create a separate class for "nonhumans."  Never-the-less, your answer got me thinking - cat can be skinned many ways.  Perhaps an interface could be implemented for "Addressable" models.